# Interpreting the output tables from point distance measures from two coordinates in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, point, distance

I have recently used ArcGIS and prior to this I have no experience with it. I wanted to calculate the distances between Care Homes in England to NHS hospitals. Basically I wanted to see how many Care Homes were there within a radius of 10 km to each hospital. I used the point distance method and in the options menu in the search radius option I specified 10 kilometers.

[image]

This is the resultant table that I get.

My query is the distance column are expressed in all decimal representations and therefore I don't think they are in km. For example, the distance between INPUT_FID 0 and NEAR_FID 20168 is 0.08618273742. In terms of kilometers, the distance between their coordinates however is 7.880

Do you have any explanation as to why this discrepancy arises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically occurs when your input data is in a Geographic Coordinate System. Use a Projected Coordinate System and you should get expected results. Use the [Project Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) to  go from GCS to PCS.

The distance from the input features to near features is calculated using the linear unit of the input features' coordinate system. [see here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/point-distance.htm).

Comment: Thank you for answer. So basically the above table is right but to convert it into kilometres I simply have to use the Projected Coordinate system?

Comment: Project your input data before you calculate point distance.